# How to hibernate Windows 8 Laptop after sleep?

Tags: windows-8, laptop, sleep, hibernate

My Windows 8 Laptop is set to sleep after 60 minutes of inactivity on Battery and to hibernate after 180 minutes on Battery.

It is also set to sleep when I close the lid.

When I close the lid, it does go to sleep and stays in sleep until it reaches the 5% critical low battery and then Hibernates.

I have 'Fast Startup' turned off

I have the High Performance power plan enabled with all settings geared towards performance

Is there a setting elsewhere that may be preventing my laptop from entering hibernate after 180 minutes of sleep after I close the lid?

Comment: Did you enable “Allow wake timers” in Power Options → Sleep?

Comment: Wake timers were off ... I turned them on and to test I did the following: Set the computer to Sleep after 5 minutes and hibernate after 7. It went to sleep at 5, and woke up at 7 to the lockscreen. ... To test further, I set it to hibernate after 5 minutes and it did do that.

Comment: This is an ASUS N550JK laptop. I just updated the BIOS to the version 207. "Allow wake timers" is enabled. Sleep is set to 5 minutes. Hibernate is set to 7 minutes. I just had it successfully sleep then hibernate after the aforementioned times. I will post back once I verify that closing the lid puts it to sleep then hibernates after the specified amount of time as well.

Answer (score 0):

i also have a zenbook nx500 - what a cool machine. My solution to this was to change from sleep to hibernate on close lid, push power button etc. ALthough the re awaken process doesnt go as smoothly with many apps, esp browsers, as it does from sleep mode.

Did you manage to resolve this by updating the bios? I havent checked what bios version my nx500 is running.